# Copying first 1000 PDF files having single, double quotes in their name to another folder

Tags: pdf

I am having this folder with PDFs into it and I need to process 1000 at a time. So I need to move them into another folder, process them and delete them. For this I tried using

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f |head -1000|xargs cp -t $destdir
```

It gives error on single and double quotes in filename. There are thousands of files and I have no idea how many of them has these quotes in them.

Can anyone help me find a solution?

And I tried with the `-0` option, it did not work

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish overall? What are you doing to these PDFs? I ask becaue this might be an [x y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)... do you really need to work on 1000 PDFs at a time, and do they need to be in the same directory, or is there a better way (possibly involving find's [`-exec` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Multiple-Files))?

Comment: I have a script that stops after processing some 70k PDFs and I have 160K PDFs. I just want to process those PDFs in smaller batches. I am actually creating Indexes for search and don't want a file to be indexed more than once. Hence I want to move 60K records into a folder create indexes, get the next set and work on that. Somehow I need those segmented into different folders so I can track which ones are already processed.

Comment: Would the natural solution not be to store the filenames in a database so that you know which ones you have already mined?

Comment: Script is written by someone else, I can't complain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve the stated problem:

```
shopt -s globstar
printf '%q\0' **/*.pdf | xargs -0 -L 1000 cp -t $destdir
```

The first line enables the globstar option for bash, so that `**` gives you a recursive search. Since `printf` is a bash builtin on Ubuntu, it [should have no problems](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/) with large numbers of files.

The first argument given to `printf` tells it how to format all the other arguments. `%q` tells it to escape everything that might cause trouble with a `\` -- so `foo bar'baz` will become `foo\ bar\'baz`. The `\0` tells it to insert a null character after each quoted string (equivalent to using `-print0` in find), which can then be picked apart by `xargs`'s `-0` option. If you need to use newline-delimited names -- which, I think, you do, since you'll need a combination of `head` and `tail` to do batches of files -- then you should use `\n` instead of `\0`:

```
printf '%q\n' **/*.pdf | head -1000 | xargs cp -t $destdir
```

---

With all that said, you might be better off [calling you script directly from `find`](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Multiple-Files) -- then you don't have to worry about escaping or quoting anything:

```
find . -type f -exec your_script '{}' \+
```

Comment: It helped me copy files without any errors. There seems to be errors but that didn't stop the copying. All the files that gave error I can move them at the end using find and copy, Thanks @evilsoup ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-print0` option, then use [this method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75186/how-to-do-head-and-tail-on-null-delimited-input-in-bash) to apply `head` on it:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | tr '\0\n' \n\0' | 
    head -1000 | tr '\0\n' \n\0' | xargs --null cp -t $destdir
```

Note that `xargs` has a `-L` option, which specifies how many arguments it should read at once from the input. Thus, depending on the processing you have to do, you could skip the `head`, write a script which takes a 1000 arguments, or even do the processing via `xargs` directly.

Comment: I don't think this would actually help. It seems that the problem is with filenames like `foo'bar` and `baz"bing` -- where the quotes will confuse the shell. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to solve this in the find documentation, so it'll probably need a different approach entirely.